# Why I cant vertical align elements in bootstrap column?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Whenever I try to add this class to my column `d-flex align-items-center` it doesn't align vertically. I do not know why. It only centers the text at the top. It always worked for me before and now it doesn't.

```
<section class="functions">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="img/screen.png" class="screens">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center">
        <h4>Functions</h4>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you miss a div </div> for <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center"> , add it and try a gain. And can you posting your code in code snippets?

Comment: As said by @Khanh Le Tran, you missed a `</div>`. However, our code works without trouble: [Have a look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o89v34ny/8/).

Comment: I wonder you want to align vertical but d-flex give you a horizontal align. Why you use d-flex ( it will give you flex display: all item in one row) As i understand you want to align your <li> in vertical right ?